# How to passing dynamic values to custom annotation for mappings from Java data.properties

Tags: java, annotations, testng, selenium-chromedriver

Im implementing an automation test with Selenium/TestNG and Im using a tool that provides custom annotation which takes strings.
I was trying to pass dynamic values from data.properties and I tried different way but I get this error constantly:
the annotation value must be constant expression

```
public class MapData {

       // fetch value from data.properties and store it as string   
      public static final String TESTNAME = LoadProps.INSTANCE.loadProps().getProperty("TestName1");
      public static final String ABC = "ABC";

}
```

and this is my test sample:

```
@Custom(name = "login")
@Test(priority = 1)
public void login() throws InterruptedException, IOException {...}
```

Annotation

```
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={METHOD})
public abstract @interface Custom extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation 
{

    public abstract java.lang.String name();

}
```

I tried to pass the dynamic value which is reading from data.properties like this:

```
@Custom(name = MapData.TESTNAME)
```

but i got that run-time error
if you look at my MapData class i have another string as ABC which i stored a string directly. when i use this way of passing:

```
@Custom(name = MapData.ABC)
```

its fine and I dont have any error! what is difference? both way are passing string.
is there any way to fetch data from data.properties and pass it to annotation?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using annotation you can't assign dynamic value to annotation parameter. However, as it's your custom annotation, so while processing annotation you can process value. For example:

```java
 String tValue = custom.name();
 String value = data.getProperty(tValue,tValue);
```

Alternate is, you can try with [QAF-TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) has [meta-data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario-meta-data.html#example-java) support where you can use parameters as below:

```
@Test(description="This is example scenario in BDD",groups={"grp1","grp2"})
@MetaData("{'env':'${target.env}','TestID':'12345'}"
public void example(){

}
```

in above example `${target.env}` is [property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html) and will get resolved at runtime.
You can access meta-data as below:

```
ITestNGMethod testMethod = testResult.getMethod()
TestNGScenario scenario = (TestNGScenario) testMethod;  
Map<String, Object> metadata = scenario.getMetaData();
```